# Null Pointer Assistance.

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Firstly, i have done research on what Null pointer means and i have read the below but i am still completely lost.

[What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

My error is

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at EBIAlarmUI$2.alarm1ButtonActionPerformed(EBIAlarmUI.java:113)
at EBIAlarmUI$2.actionPerformed(EBIAlarmUI.java:109)
```

And this is the code that is causing it.

```
alarm1Button = new JButton();
    alarm1Button.setText("Alarm 1");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_alarm1Button = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_alarm1Button.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_alarm1Button.gridx = 9;
    gbc_alarm1Button.gridy = 2;
    getContentPane().add(alarm1Button, gbc_alarm1Button);

    alarm1Button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            alarm1ButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
        public synchronized void alarm1ButtonActionPerformed(
                java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            resultsTextArea.setText("Alarm 1 Activated, String: " + alarm1);

            try {
                byte[] b = alarm1.getBytes("ASCII");

                TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter sw = new 
    TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter(
                        twoWaySerCom.serialPort.getOutputStream());

                sw.out.write(b);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Do something to handle the exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Specifically these 2 lines.

```
alarm1ButtonActionPerformed(evt);
```

and

```
resultsTextArea.setText("Alarm 1 Activated, String: " + alarm1);
```

The exact code worked a few hours ago before i moved from a GroupLayout to a GridBag layout.

So either  resultsTextArea or alarm1 are Null? I dont understand how that can be.  They appear in my GUI

```
JTextArea resultsTextArea = new JTextArea();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_resultsTextArea = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_resultsTextArea.gridwidth = 3;
    gbc_resultsTextArea.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_resultsTextArea.gridx = 7;
    gbc_resultsTextArea.gridy = 7;
    getContentPane().add(resultsTextArea, gbc_resultsTextArea);
```

and i even tried adding them to my variables declaration

```
public javax.swing.JTextArea resultsTextArea;
public javax.swing.JTextArea customStringTextArea;
public javax.swing.JButton alarm1Button;
String alarm1 = "$81,$01,$06,$01,$10,$10,$03,$01,$FF";
String alarm2 = "*993R03,67,6#";
String alarm3 = "*994R14,67,1#";
```

Comment: you can use **java.util.Optional** if you are using java 1.8 version

Answer (score 2):

`resultsTextArea` is `null`.  It's `null` because you're shadowing your variables.

First of all, you decleare an instance field...

```
public javax.swing.JTextArea resultsTextArea;
```

But when you initialise it, you're creating a local version...

```
JTextArea resultsTextArea = new JTextArea();
```

Which means that when you try to reference the instance field from the `ActionListener`, it is `null`.

Remove the second decleration...

```
//JTextArea resultsTextArea = new JTextArea();
resultsTextArea = new JTextArea();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,  I see where i went wrong now.  I have just started using Eclipse over Netbeans as a lot of tutorials use it.  I notice that a lot of problems seem to go away when i restart Eclipse.  Is that something that happens to you?

Comment: I don't use Eclipse, I use Netbeans.  But you might find that the caches used by both tend to get out of sync with what's really happening and need to be "cleaned" up regularly.